# How to check Checkbox with Jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have the following piece of code :

```
for(var i = 0, len = data.UserDetail.RoleNames.length; i < len; ++i) {
    var rolevalue = data.UserDetail.RoleNames[i];
    //alert(rolevalue)

    $('input[value = rolevalue]').attr('checked', true); // I am getting a exception in this line !! :(
}
```

I am not able to check the values which are already present in the checkbox. The checkbox is having the following value

```
<input type="checkbox" name="role" value="Admin1" />Admin1<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="role" value="Admin2" />Admin2<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="role" value="Admin3" />Admin3<br />

<input type="checkbox" name="role" value="Admin4" />Admin4<br />
```

What will be syntax? I have also tried using the `prop()` function as well but it does not work.

Answer (score 3):

It seems a bit of an odd way to do things, but I'm guessing what you want is:

`$('input[value=' + rolevalue + ']').attr('checked', true)`

I'm not 100% sure that the selector works this way, but if it does, that code will be better than yours!

Comment: Yipeeee it worked after I made minor modification :$('input[value="' + rolevalue + '"]').attr('checked', true)

Answer (score 0):

This will work too:

```
$('input[value='" + rolevalue + "']').is(':checked');
```